# fetch multiple data from object

Tags: php, object

i m using mind body api to fetch data. i have n object that contains the following data, i need to fetch all the id firstname and lastname and store it in database. i have shown the data here only till  `[3] => stdClass Object`, but the original list is long.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 100000173
            [FirstName] => a
            [LastName] => b
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 100000174
            [FirstName] => c
            [LastName] => d
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 100000175
            [FirstName] => e
            [LastName] => f
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 100000176
            [FirstName] => g
            [LastName] => h
        )
)
```

I received the above result from the following code..

```
$MBclients = $classService->GetClients(array());
if(intval($MBclients->GetClientsResult->ResultCount) > 0)
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($MBclients->GetClientsResult->Clients->Client);//die;
    }
```

The code that i tried to fetch data is

```
$info = $MBclients->id; 
echo $info;
```

But it didn't showed any result. can anyone tell how to fetch the result

Comment: Since your object is from `print_r($MBclients->GetClientsResult->Clients->Client)` have you tried `foreach($MBclients->GetClientsResult->Clients->Client as $Client){ echo $Client->ID; }`?

Comment: @Sean thanks it worked, can u plz tell that if i would do something like this.. $result=$MBclients->GetClientsResult->Clients->Client Then also same method would work?

Comment: You can do `$MBclients->GetClientsResult->Clients->Client[0]->ID` to get the id of the 1st array. You would change the `[0]`, ie. `[1]` to change the array, and change the `->ID`, ie. `->FirstName` to get a different property